# How do I sync ML Kit detect in Flutter with a video timestamp?

Tags: flutter, firebase-mlkit, google-mlkit, mediapipe

I am new to Flutter, and creating a project using Flutter with the ML Kit plugin running pose detection in stream mode, and also utilizing the Flutter Video player running a video from https link.  My question is for example, I wanted to perform multiple different types of detections, but in sync with the video, what is the best way to accomplish this?
What this means is that
0:01 - 1:00 Detection Type 1
1:01 - 1:59 Detection Type 2
2:00 - 2:59 Detection Type 3

So basically the information will come from my backend before the start of the video, and I want to be able to assign various different detection methods based upon the timestamps of the https video.

Thank you.